# how make multiple user can-register to their respective activity in Android using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

> ```
> 'package com.raojee.getleave.activity; import android.content.Intent; import android.os.Bundle; import
> ```
>
> android.text.TextUtils; import android.view.View; import
> android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation; import
> android.widget.Button; import android.widget.LinearLayout; import
> android.widget.Toast;
>
> import androidx.annotation.NonNull; import
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; import
> androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
>
> import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot; import
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError; import
> com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener; import
> com.raojee.getleave.R; import
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener; import
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task; import
> com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText; import
> com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult; import
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth; import
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser; import
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; import
> com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; import
> com.raojee.getleave.fragment.DailyInTakeFragment; import
> com.raojee.getleave.fragment.EmpPersFragment; import
> com.raojee.getleave.fragment.PersonalFragment; import
> com.raojee.getleave.model.User;
>
> public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
> View.OnClickListener {
> View myView;
> boolean isUp;
> private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
> private TextInputEditText txtLoginEmail;
> private TextInputEditText txtLoginPassword;
> private Button btnLogin;
> private Button openRegBtn;
> private TextInputEditText txtRegEmail;
> private TextInputEditText txtRegPassword;
> private TextInputEditText txtCnfPassword;
> private Button btnRegister;
> private Button closeRegBtn;
> private FirebaseUser currentUser;
> private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
> private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
>
> ```
> public RegisterActivity(){
>
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
>     initView();
>
>     mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
>
>     isUp = false;
>     myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
> }
>
>
> private void register(final String email, String password) {
>
>     mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
>             .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
>                     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>                         currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
>                         moveToMainActivity(email);
>                     } else {
>                         Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
>                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                     }
>
>                     // .
>                 }
>             });
> }
>
> private void login(final String email, String password) {
>     mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
>             .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
>                     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>                         currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
>
>
>
>                                 String uid = currentUser.getUid();
>
>                                 database.getReference().child("users").child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new
> ```
>
> ValueEventListener() {
> @Override
> public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
>
> ```
>                                         String usertype = snapshot.child("users").getValue(String.class);
>                                         if (usertype == ("Admin")){
>                                             moveToMainActivity(email);
>                                         }
>                                         else if (usertype == ("Employee")){
>                                             Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, EmpMainActivity.class);
>                                             startActivity(intent);
>                                         }
>
>                                     }
>
>                                     @Override
>                                     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
>
>                                     }
>                                 });
>
>
>
>
>                     }
>
>                     else {
>                         Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
>                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                     }
>
>                     // ...
>                 }
>             });
> }
>
> private void moveToMainActivity(String email) {
>     startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class).putExtra("email",email));
>     finish();
> }
>
> // slide the view from below itself to the current position
> public void slideUp(View view) {
>     view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     closeRegBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     txtCnfPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     txtRegEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     btnRegister.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     txtRegPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
>             0,                 // fromXDelta
>             0,                 // toXDelta
>             view.getHeight(),  // fromYDelta
>             0);                // toYDelta
>     animate.setDuration(500);
>     animate.setFillAfter(true);
>     view.startAnimation(animate);
> }
>
> // slide the view from its current position to below itself
> public void slideDown(View view) {
>     TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
>             0,                 // fromXDelta
>             0,                 // toXDelta
>             0,                 // fromYDelta
>             view.getHeight()); // toYDelta
>     animate.setDuration(500);
>     animate.setFillAfter(true);
>     view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>     closeRegBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>     btnRegister.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>     txtCnfPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>     txtRegEmail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>     txtRegPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>     view.startAnimation(animate);
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public void onClick(View v) {
>     switch (v.getId()) {
>         case R.id.closeRegBtn:
>             slideDown(myView);
>             isUp = !isUp;
>             break;
>         case R.id.btnLogin:
>         case R.id.btnRegister:
>             submit(v.getId());
>             break;
>         case R.id.openRegBtn:
>             slideUp(myView);
>             isUp = !isUp;
>             break;
>     }
> }
>
> private void initView() {
>     txtLoginEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLoginEmail);
>     txtLoginPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLoginPassword);
>     btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
>     openRegBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openRegBtn);
>     txtRegEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRegEmail);
>     txtRegPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRegPassword);
>     txtCnfPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCnfPassword);
>     btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
>     closeRegBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeRegBtn);
>     myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
>
>     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
>     openRegBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
>     btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
>     closeRegBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onStart() {
>     super.onStart();
>     currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
>     if(currentUser != null){
>         moveToMainActivity(currentUser.getEmail());
>     }
> }
>
> private void submit(int id) {
>     // validate
>     if(!isUp){
>         String txtLoginEmailString = txtLoginEmail.getText().toString().trim();
>         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtLoginEmailString)) {
>             Toast.makeText(this, "txtLoginEmailString不能为空", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             return;
>         }
>
>         String txtLoginPasswordString = txtLoginPassword.getText().toString().trim();
>         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtLoginPasswordString)) {
>             Toast.makeText(this, "txtLoginPasswordString不能为空", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             return;
>         }
>
>         login(txtLoginEmailString,txtLoginPasswordString);
>     }
>     else{
>         String txtRegEmailString = txtRegEmail.getText().toString().trim();
>         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtRegEmailString)) {
>             Toast.makeText(this, "txtRegEmailString不能为空", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             return;
>         }
>
>         String txtRegPasswordString = txtRegPassword.getText().toString().trim();
>         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtRegPasswordString)) {
>             Toast.makeText(this, "txtRegPasswordString不能为空", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             return;
>         }
>
>         String txtCnfPasswordString = txtCnfPassword.getText().toString().trim();
>         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtCnfPasswordString)) {
>             Toast.makeText(this, "txtCnfPasswordString不能为空", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             return;
>         }
>         if (!txtCnfPasswordString.equals(txtRegPasswordString)) {
>             Toast.makeText(this, "txtCnfPasswordString不能为空", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             return;
>         }
>
>         register(txtRegEmailString,txtRegPasswordString);
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onBackPressed() {
>     if(isUp){
>         slideDown(myView);
>         isUp = !isUp;
>     }
>     else{
>         super.onBackPressed();
>     }
>
> } }'
> ```
>
> > Blockquote

Comment: Where are you storing the roles? In database as in the answer above or custom claims?

Comment: i store in database but error in login 
"Attempt to invoke id null"

Comment: you should manage `role` instead of comparing `email`. When user provide email and pwd, If its correct, check role against this user and redirect to respected screen.